# What is the right way to include an external cesiumjs library via external cdn with meteorjs?

Tags: javascript, meteor, cesiumjs

I am using meteorjs, I want to use cesiumjs. My code is as follows:

In my client code in my startup js file:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');  // optional
  script.setAttribute('src', 'http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.18/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

In a template I have, I include the div for the "cesiumContainer", and have inside of mytemplate.js:

```
Template.mytemplate.rendered = function() {
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
};
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 ReferenceError: Cesium is not defined
    at Template.mytemplate.rendered (mytemplate.js:4)
```

For my CSS, I just include it in the index.html page within the "client" directory in the "head" tag (is this not right to do?):

```
  <style>
    @import url(http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.18/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
    #cesiumContainer {
      width: 100%; height: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
```

How do I properly include this external library into my meteorjs application? Also, if I have a mytemplate2 that shows up on the same page (I am using FlowLayout), how do I properly get access to the "viewer" variable? Is it customary to just set it to a "global" VIEWER variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no meteor expert, but I'll point out that your script load is asynchronous.  You need to wait for the `onload` event to be fired by the `script` tag that you added, before you attempt to access Cesium.  Also, use `document.head` instead of looking up the tag.

I expect the style stuff you posted will work fine.  You can also use the classic `link rel="stylesheet"` if that's more familiar.

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.18/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js');
document.head.appendChild(script);

script.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Cesium version: ' + Cesium.VERSION;
}

// Cesium is undefined here.  Call your code from the onload handler above.
```

```html
<p id="msg">Loading...</p>
```